# sorting is not working

Tags: asp.net

when i m trying to sort in grid view without ispostback property then sorintg is done, but when i m using ispoastback property on page_load then it is not working. please suggest me some solution...here is my code

```
   private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
   {
       string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

       switch (sortDirection)
       {
           case SortDirection.Ascending:
               newSortDirection = "ASC";
               break;

           case SortDirection.Descending:
               newSortDirection = "DESC";
               break;
       }

       return newSortDirection;
   }    

   protected void grd_productMaster_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
   {
       DataTable dataTable = grd_productMaster.DataSource as DataTable;

       if (dataTable != null)
       {
           DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
          dataView = (DataView)Session["dataview"];
           if (Session["dataview"] != null)
           {
               dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection);

              grd_productMaster.DataSource = dataView;

               grd_productMaster.DataBind();
           }
           else
               Response.Write("Dataview is null");

       }
   }
```

Comment: you mean to say its not working without !IsPostBack (not ispostback) ? please send the code written in Page_Load

Comment: What does _"when i m using ispoastback property on page_load then it is not working"_ mean? If you databind your GridView on postbacks(before the event was triggered) the sorting event(or any other) will not fire.

Comment: sorting is not working if i have give ispostback property...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you've databound the GridView in Page_Load on postbacks. This will prevent the GridView from firing events. Instead you should only DataBind it `if(!IsPostback)`.

Of course then  `grd_productMaster.DataSource` always will be `null` but you don't need it at the first place. You only need the `SortExpression` to load your DataSource accordingly, for example [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602015/gridview-sorting-question/6602125#6602125).

Comment: can u send me the correct code for my question.

Comment: because i m trying this from last two days...please help me out with this

Comment: @user1280428: Have a look at my provided link where you can find also a C# example.

Comment: ya i saw that code but i didnt get where i should have to change my code.

Comment: @user1280428: I'm not sure what you don't understand. `BindGrid()` in my linked answer is a method where i encapsulate the data-loading(f.e. a sql query with the `SortExpression` in the `Order By`) and the `GridView.DataSource=...; GridView.DataBind()` stuff.